# Hide submit type input value from url

Tags: javascript, php, html, forms

I have a form with GET method with some inputs like this:

```
<input type="text" name="something">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here to submit form">
```

I don't want the url to become

```
mypage.php?something=value&submit=Click+here+to+submit+form
```

I want to suppress the submit parameter in the url (should be like this: mypage.php?something=value).

I  need only GET method please don't mention POST method. 
Also you may mention to remove `name="submit"` but i need it also to identify this submit.

Also if there is a input from which is empty i don't want to show

```
<input type="text" name="input1">
<input type="text" name="input2">
<input type="submit" name="submit" value="Click here to submit form">
```

`input1` gets value but if `input2` doesn't have value the i want url like
mypage.php?input1=value

Thanks

Comment: What is the technical limitation that is preventing you from utilizing `POST`?

Comment: You can do it using javascript. Have the submit button outside the form, and when submit is clicked, using javascript submit the form.

Comment: Is possible hidden value if field is empty with javascript, but if you need to get value from submit button, is not possible to hidden this value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you don't want the `submit` parameter to show up in your `GET` request URL, don't give it a name, and instead use `id` or `class` to identify it uniquely:

```
<input type="submit" id="submit" value="Click here to submit form">
```

Comment: Thanks esqew. I already mention i need the name="submit" for more work.

Comment: @SharifAhmed - this is the only way to do this as you describe. You should consider re-structuring your code to make use of the `id` or `class` attributes, as this will allow you to take a similar approach without having your `submit` value appear in your URL.

Comment: I need this to check if the submit button click and input value is given
if(isset($_GET[submit])  &&  !empty($_GET['select_card']) )

Comment: @SharifAhmed If you need to check the value of a GET variable, there is no way around having it appear at the tail end of your URL (without some workaround trickery)

Answer (score 1):

I would remove form submit the  and just turn it into a button.  Then I would use jquery to submit the form and do any logic processing.

```
<input type="test" id="favoriteCheese" value="nacho" />
<button id="submit" value="Click here to submit form">Click here to submit form</button>

$("#submit").on('click', function () {
    var data = {};
    var favCheese = $("#favCheese").val();
    if(favCheese.length > 0) {
        data.favCheese = favCheese
    }
    $.ajax({
        url : ".../mypage.php",
        data : data,
        type : 'GET',
        ...
    })
})
```